# Jquery index doesn't work for child nodes

Tags: jquery, indexing

I would like to index everything in document and then call it by its index. The HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
</ul>
```

Alert to get index:

```
alert('Index: ' + $('#foo').index());
```

The problem is that it alerts number `0` for both `ul` and `#foo`. I understand the logic of this but I need them in order, so the `ul` should count for `0` and `#foo` should be `1`.

What can I try to get this type of indexing? I tried `prevAll()` but that gives the same result.

PS Please not this is just an example, in reality the code should work on large documents.

[Example code](http://jsfiddle.net/p83Rg/12/)

Comment: do you mean you need 'the child hold index+1 from the parent?

Comment: @Charlie I'm not sure..I don't know how that code would look like and how it will work on large documents. I can imagine not all items in document are child of something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index()` without arguments will look for the index of an element within it's parent.
But you can call it with an argument to surpass that.

Suppose we're working on your example

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
</ul>
```

A solution could look like this:

```
$('ul, li').index($('ul'))   // => 0
$('ul, li').index($('#foo')) // => 1
$('ul, li').index($('#bar')) // => 2
```

You can even do this programatically:

```
$('ul, li').each(function(i) {
  console.log(this.tagName + (!!this.id ? " #" + this.id : "") + " = " + i)
})

// UL     => 0
// LI#foo => 1
// LI#bar => 2
```

Just be aware, that `$(selector).index(element)` will return the index of the `element` within the Nodes matched by `selector`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for:) If I put the all selector `*` it also gives me head meta title etc. Wonderful

Comment: I think the reverse syntax is a little more readable: `$(selector1).index(selector2)`, where `selector1` is searched for in `selector2`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$.fn.tree_index = function() {
    var index = -1;

    $(this).parents().each(function() {
        index += $(this).index() + 1;
    });

    return index;
}

alert('Index: ' + $('#foo').tree_index());
```

Comment: Thank you:) that seems to do the trick. I see this in the code `(!$this.is('body, html'))` Is it really necessary?

Comment: Hi if I put `<span></span>` in the bottom it gives me index `2`. Any ideas on how to make that index `4`?

Comment: Wel the problem is I don't know how the documents look like upfront so refering to elements is something I can't do. I have to refer to everything * and than index it